# jQuery 1.9.1 selection by tag name returns only the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, tagname

I'm developing an userscript for Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey that removes the *onmousedown* attribute from  tags in Google search results pages.

The plugin indicates that the script is running, the script is executed, but nothing happen.

I've opened the console and tried to do it manually, but the selector selects only the first  in the page.

I've tried with:

```
$("a")
$("a.l")
$(".l")
```

I've also tried to change the position of the userscript at document-start, document-body and document-end, but the result is the same: only the first element that matches is returned.

Script code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Google onmousedown remove
// @version    0.1
// @include      /^https?://[a-z]*\.?google\.[a-z\.]+/search.*/
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
// @run-at     document-end
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function (){
    $("a.l").each(function (){ $(this).removeAttr("onmousedown"); });
});
```

Where's the problem? Thanks.

Comment: google is not running jquery btw, don't know if that's the problem

Comment: jQuery is included by the script at line 5.

Comment: ok but if you go on google and to $('.l') in console you get the first element (without any jquery) so they use $ for something.
try using jQuery.noConflict() and then using jQuery instead of $

Comment: Are you running this directly on a Google results page? I think `$` is NOT jQuery on those pages. Google assigns some other value to that variable (which also acts as a selector engine) and there's no jQuery.

Comment: I have also met the same issue, how do you solve it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336120/jquery-returns-only-the-first-object-by-given-selector-instead-of-array-when-bui

Comment: The same issue for me, how do you solve it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40336120/jquery-returns-only-the-first-object-by-given-selector-instead-of-array-when-bui

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to type `$` in console being on search page you will see something different from usual `function (e,t){return new i.fn.init(e,t,u)}` that is defined by jQuery. So...

Seems like Google defines its own `$` function and it behaves differently. The simplest solution would be to use `jQuery` explicitly instead of `$`: `jQuery('a.l')`.

But it is to long so here is the trick from the jQuery for it: instead of document.ready, invoke [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) function and pass it the function with argument `$`. Then inside this function `$` equals `jQuery`.

```
jQuery(function ($){
    $("a.l").each(function (){ $(this).removeAttr("onmousedown"); });
});
```

Not tested, but should work.