# jQuery returns only the first object by given selector instead of array when building with webpack + es6, unexpected.

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6, webpack

As you know, jQuery always return an array of objects by given selector (e.g: $(‘a')), it works well for my previous projects. Recently we move to ES6 + webpack, $(‘a’) only returns the first object, instead of the whole array, strange, does any guys have the same experience? or any change for jQuery, es6 and webpack? Please share and thanks in advance.

PS:
jQuery version V2.2.4,  node version V6.3.1 for webpack projects.

Comment: Any chance you can add a code snippet or reduced test case?

Comment: Pls see https://github.com/jianhua1982/todo/blob/master/src/client/app.js , the bottom line debug function.

Comment: `jQuery()` does not return an array, it returns a jQuery object. What is the actual problem?

Comment: Normally jQuery will always return an array of DOM elements.

Comment: I have similiar problem: for `$("body")` I get `<body data-view-class="Views.Sales.Instores.IndexView" data-vars-user-id="1" data-vars-user-username="Administrator ">` with webpack, instead of `Object { 0: <body>, length: 1, prevObject: Object, context: HTMLDocument → instores, selector: "body" }` (direct requiring from CDN).

Comment: My setup (using webpacker gem)  `import {} from 'jquery';` in `application.js` and `new webpack.ProvidePlugin({

    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    jquery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
` in plugins

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selector does not return an Array object. Instead it returns a custom jQuery object that behaves like an array.

You can access the entries using subscript (`$('a')[5]`) and it also has a property called `length` that reflects its size, but it is not of Array type.

---

For example:
 `var list = $('a');`

`list` will then be:
`jQuery.fn.init[234]` where 234 happens to the number of elements the selector matched.

Then doing a `typeof list` returns `"object"`. Even if it  matched only one element, it will still act like an Array, having a size of 1.

---

However, you can turn it into an Array by using the `jQuery.makeArray(obj)` function.

For example: `var array = $.makeArray(list)` will turn it into Array which will return  `true` when you call `$.isArray(array)` on it.